# Excel Online - Enter Array Formula

Tags: excel, office-web-apps

In Microsoft Excel entering an array formula requires using the keyboard combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

How can I enter an array formula in Excel Online (the WebApp version of Excel).  Is there an alternate method. Insert > Array Formula or something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to SharePoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you can view existing array formulas and their results but not create them within Excel Online.  One option is to hit the "Open in Excel" button, which downloads the file for local editing.  After editing, the file can be reuploaded back to OneDrive.

[Excel Online Docs: Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Overview-of-formulas-34519A4E-1E8D-4F4B-84D4-D642C4F63263)

> Excel Online doesn’t support creating array formulas. You can view the
>   results of array formulas created in Excel desktop application, but
>   you can’t edit or recalculate them. If you have the Excel desktop
>   application, click Open in Excel to work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on bottom right green square

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Will repeat formula on whole column

Comment: That is not what an Array Formula is. Array Formulas are single formulas in a single cell that execute calculations over multiple arrays of cells simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a "**CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**" to prepare a array formula. Write array formula, then **ONLY USE ENTER**.